Understanding non-ideal inductor model's \$R_{parallel}\$ resistor
I am looking at this paper, which shows a non-ideal inductor model:

I am not sure where Rp comes from. Rp suggests that the current can flow through the non-deal inductor element without going through the actual inductor wire. I understand that Cs can do that (let the current pass through the inductor without going through the actual inductor wire, in high(er) frequencies.)
Is Rp a parasitic capacitance inside/due to Cs?

From what I remember the magnetic core losses in the inductor are modeled by a parallel resistor.

Do you mean non-ideal?

@MathKeepsMeBusy fixed it


So Rp must be a parasitic capacitance inside/due to Cs, right?

Unlikely.
Typically, \$R_P>>R_S\$. \$R_S\$ usually represents the resistance of windings on \$L\$, and can be measured with a multimeter with a DC current.
\$R_P\$ most often represents losses in the coil... The inductor might radiate away some electromagnetic energy, or perhaps skin effect of inductor windings. Hysteresis and eddy current losses might be included in \$R_P\$ as well. Since all these dissipate energy, their model must be resistive. \$R_P\$ is often frequency-dependent (very large at DC).
At some high frequency, interwinding capacitance \$C_S\$ in your diagram causes the whole shebang to resonate, leaving you with something approaching \$R_P\$. Above this frequency, it is a lossy capacitor.

A element in an equivalent circuit does not necessarily have a physical interpretation (although in many cases it does). Elements are added because they result in a better match between measured terminal impedance (or admittance) as a function of frequency. In many cases in a particular device some elements may be totally negligible.

\$R_P\$ represents the total core losses of the inductor, which can include things like eddy currents causing energy to be lost as heat, so it's not necessarily  current flowing in one side and out the other like an actual resistor.
